# Using a checkbox to use a custom formula gives error message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm trying to use a custom formula I've seen on a few different websites to count cells with a specific background color. As it is (see below), it works just fine.

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

However, I need the formula to recalculate, so I attempted to put the custom function inside an **if** function, where the true condition is if a specific checkbox is true.

`=if($a$41,countColoredCells(D4:D36,$BX$6), " ")`

If the checkbox is not selected, I get the proper result,but if it is selected, I get an error message: "Exception: Range not found (line 7)." I'm not sure why I'm getting this message when, if I am not using the if formula, the custom function works just fine by itself.

What am I missing? What is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a result of these regular expressions finding different/additional matches:

> /((.*),/

> /,(.*))/

It is intended to reference this formula structure:

> =countColoredCells(D4:D36, $BX$6)

But you now have it looking for matches within this formula:

> =if($A$41, countColoredCells(D4:D36, $BX$6), " ")

Here is a modified version with an optional parameter for your conditional cell.

```js
function countColoredCells(countRange, colorRef, ifRange = true) {
  if (!ifRange) return;
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula().split(/\(/)[1].split(/\)/)[0].split(/,/);
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula[0].trim();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula[1].trim();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

With this, your new formula would be

> =countColoredCells(D4:D36, $BX$6, $A$41)

Comment: I won't pretend I understand the split bits in the code, but the rest of it makes sense to me (in my limited knowledge). However, now it says there's an exception error on line 13, range not found. I'm comparing the two different sub-sections (rangeA1 vs colorCellA1), but I'm not seeing anything obvious that would cause it to fail for the True condition (it works fine for the False condition).

Comment: Double check that your ranges aren't out of bounds and you are using the custom formula by itself. I tested it on my own sheets and it seemed to function with and without an ifRange checkbox reference

Both "=countColoredCells(B7:F8,B7,G3)" and "=countColoredCells(B7:F8,B7)" worked on my own sheets

Comment: I've updated the function; forgot to trim whitespace on the A1 notations. It was likely trying to perform getRange() on " $BX$6" instead of "$BX$6" in your case.

Comment: I follow. I see the .trim bit added. So that makes the function trim (D4:D36, $BX$6, $A$41) to (D4:D36,$BX$6,$A$41), more or less, yeah?

Comment: Basically, yes. Specifically, it's trimming the elements within an array `["D4:D36", " $BX$6", " $A$41"]`